# Entity Framework code-first filter data on database and read it from EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, entity-framework-6

I have a C# project with EF code-first approach. The purpose is to do crud operations. My web app will be hosted under IIS under two folders

1. web app
2. WCF service

The application will pass user credentials to the WCF service and then to SQL Server database. Code first approach works well in this case.

READ scenario: the data  needs to be filtered on the database level, not on application level. So I cannot directly call tables while querying SQL using EF. User will not have read access on the tables but only on views. The SQL views will have responsibility to filter the data and then pass to the service.

The question is how to proceed with EF code first approach in a way that I can leverage the benefits of EF migration s and then map the tables to the SQL views. Can anyone explain how to proceed with this read scenarios and best approach?

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework doesn't support mapping to Sql views but you can do the following:

1. Create an entity class that mapping your (sql) view structure.
2. Add a new **empty** migration using the `add-migration -IgnoreChanges` command since you don't want your entities to map to tables.
3. In this migration you can create (Up method) your Sql view.

It is important to note that you have to indicate the Sql view name in your entity ("view entity?") configuration (mapping) class:

```
public class FooConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Foo>
{
    public FooConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("ViewName");
        HasKey(p => p.Id); // You also have to configure a key
    }
}
```

This article from Julie Lerman could be interesting for you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn519921.aspx